# dompdf generates a pdf empty / corrupted

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf, dompdf

I have a problem with dompdf. I'm trying to generate a PDF file through the values of a form.
A user enters the website, fills out the fields and clicks submit. In my email I must attach a PDF with all the form values.
I was able to integrate it into my code, but there is something wrong.
To submit, I get the mail with the PDF, but it is damaged. (Of 0BYTE.)

The code I've entered in includes / ajax.php.
This is the code:

```html
      // Generate PDF here
      require_once("../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
   spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
        
      $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
      $dompdf->load_html($message); 
      $dompdf->render(); 
      $pdf_content = $dompdf->output();
      file_put_contents('../dompdf/ordine.pdf',$pdfoutput);
```

data users write in the form are in $message

this is my [ajax.php](http://pastebin.com/9P5SyVns)

Comment: Unless its a typo.. `$pdfoutput` is not defined. Your variable you want to save is called `$pdf_content`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
// Generate PDF here
  require_once("../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
  $dompdf->load_html($message); 
  $dompdf->render(); 
  $pdf_content = $dompdf->output();
  file_put_contents('../dompdf/ordine.pdf',$pdf_content);  //there was a typo here...
```

You pdf was correctly 0 bytes because you write an undefined variable to it.

Comment: No problem ;) you can accept or upvote the answer if you like.